# jQuery callbacks messing with variable scopes and functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning people - I've been having this problem for hours and I can't isolate it.

I have this piece of jQueryzed JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var validated = 1;

    jQuery('#help_continue').click(function() {
        jQuery('#step' + validated + ', #step' + validated + '_help').fadeOut(200, function() {
            jQuery('#step' + validated + '_help').removeClass('visible').find('.visible').removeClass('visible');
            jQuery('#step' + (validated + 1) + '_help').addClass('visible');
            jQuery('#step' + (validated + 1) + '_help div:first').addClass('visible').css({display: 'block'});
            jQuery('#step' + (validated + 1) + ', #step' + (validated + 1) + '_help').fadeIn(200);
        });
    });
});
```

All good, nothing too fancy. If bound to HTML, it works as expected.

The thing is that, when I add this to the mix:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var validated = 1;

    jQuery('#help_continue').click(function() { 
        jQuery('#step' + validated + ', #step' + validated + '_help').fadeOut(200, function() {
            jQuery('#step' + validated + '_help').removeClass('visible').find('.visible').removeClass('visible');
            jQuery('#step' + (validated + 1) + '_help').addClass('visible');
            jQuery('#step' + (validated + 1) + '_help div:first').addClass('visible').css({display: 'block'});
            jQuery('#step' + (validated + 1) + ', #step' + (validated + 1) + '_help').fadeIn(200); alert(validated); // this...
        });
        validated++; // ...and this.
    });
});
```

The alert it shown TWICE, and the "validated" variable is NEVER = 1 inside the function - always 2.

I'm no JavaScript guru for sure, but I definitely know that that's just plain wrong, unless I'm missing something. I come from a PHP background, and I know that JavaScript has its idiosyncrasies, but this is just weird.

I'm using jQuery 1.5 if it matters. Anyone knows what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you pass as callback to `fadeOut` is only executed after ~200ms timeout. But the the code is not blocking. I.e. everything inside the click handler, also statements after the call to `fadeOut`, is executed immediately.

```
jQuery('#help_continue').click(function() {
    // first 
    jQuery('....').fadeOut(200, function() {
        // second
    });
    validated++; // first
});
```

But this should not show the alert twice... anyway, if you want to increment `validate` on click, but it should have the the correct value when the `fadeOut` callback is called, you can do so with an immediate function:

```
jQuery('#help_continue').click(function() {       
    (function(validated) {
        jQuery('....').fadeOut(200, function() {
            // ...
        });
    }(validated));
    validated++;
});
```

Comment: Are you saying that validated++ is being executed at the same time that the click handler is triggered and not after the animation is done? Also, I don't know what's happening with the alert - I tried setting the validated++ after the fadeIn, but still nothing.

Comment: If I set validated++ after the fadeIn and the alert outside the callback, I click twice and I get 1 and 3. If I put the alert after the fadeIn, then validated++ after the fadeIn in the callback, with one click, I get 1 and 2... It's behaving weird...

Comment: @AeroCross: Just put everything what should be executed *after* the element was faded out, *in* the callback. That is what the callback is for.

Comment: Nope - nothing. The expected behavior is that every time I fire up the click handler, validation goes up by 1. If I put it inside the callback, it adds up twice (1 click = 3) and then it stops moving up. Inside the callback it has a different behavior. I even tried setting up window.validation to prevent scoping problems, but still nothing.

Comment: After seeing your edition, I went back to Coda and tried again - for some weird reason it worked perfectly, but I didn't understand at all what just happened. Could you explain a bit what was going on in there? Perhaps telling me how's that technique called so I can do further research? I am very grateful!

Comment: @AeroCross: Sorry for the delay, I was away the whole day. What I used can be described as *immediate function*. You are basically defining a function and immediately executing it `function(){...}()`. It is nothing special, you could also just define a function a function beforehand and call. The thing is that JavaScript has only function scope. By passing a variable to the function, the function has the value of variable at the moment it was passed. It creates a new scope and changes to the variable at the outside don't affect the value inside.

Comment: I had been googling around for _immediate function_ and I've been practicing with it - I'm getting more and more the hang of function and variable scopes in JavaScript (because, as I said, I come from PHP and it's really different) and this was extremely helpful. I thank you, kind sir!